# CSS: Change colour of one menu-option while hovering with cursor above another menu-options

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can change the colour of font  and background colour of the "Register" section when I hover with the mouse cursor over the other 3 options ('Login', 'About' and 'language'). I want it only to change the colours when one of the three other options are selected.

```css
.main-menu {
  width: 170px;
}

.floating-menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 26px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 35%;
}

.floating-menu div a {
  /**text-align: center;**/
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.main-menu a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444950;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.main-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #00B200;
}

.main-menu a.active {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #00B200;
}

.main-menu a.active:hover {
  background-color: #00B200;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <a href="#">Log In</a>
  <a href="#" class="active">Register</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Language</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - do you mean change it "while hovering" or "only to change the colours when one of the three other options are selected.".. you say both! Also, is it only when *Register* option is selected or do you want the same functionality when any of the options are selected?

Comment: When I hover over/select (not click) one of the '3 other options' (for example over Language) that the colour of the text from 'Registration' is changing to for example blue.

Comment: And does the same apply when, for example, "About" is active - does hovering over the other options change the colour of "Active"? Or is this functionality only to apply for Register?

Comment: And what colour do you want to change them to? Also, are there any other options in your menu, or just these?

Comment: I want that the 'Register' color changes to blue while I hover over 'LogIn', 'About' or 'Languages'. This are the only options in my menu, there are no others.

Comment: You really need to be a bit clearer :) Do you want the font colour or background colour to be blue? You said you want to change both, so what should they both change to?

Comment: font colour to blue and background colour to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only want this to happen for the "Register" option only, you will need to add another class to it so it can be identified when we want to apply this styling to is.

So first add a class to the link in addition to the `active` class e.g.

```
<a href="#" class="active register-link">Register</a>
```

Now you need to add a style for that link that will activate when you hover over *any* link - we can achieve this by applying the style on the whole `ul` when it is hovered.
e.g.:

```
.main-menu:hover a.register-link{
  color: #0095ff;
  background: #000;
}
```

Now when we do that, it means that the register link itself stays black and blue even when you hover over it:

- If you want the Register link to be the normal **green colour on hover**, make sure you add the above style *BEFORE* the `.main-menu a.active:hover` in your CSS.
- If you want the Register link to stay **black and blue on hover**, make sure you add the above style *AFTER* the `.main-menu a.active:hover` in your CSS.

```css
.main-menu {
  width: 170px;
}

.floating-menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 26px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 35%;
}

.floating-menu div a {
  /**text-align: center;**/
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.main-menu a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444950;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.main-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #00B200;
}

.main-menu a.active {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #00B200;
}


/* if you want the Register link to be green (the normal hover colour) 
   when it is hovered add this BEFORE the .main-menu a.active CSS */

.main-menu:hover a.register-link {
  color: #0095ff;
  background: #000;
}

.main-menu a.active:hover {
  background-color: #00B200;
  color: #fff;
}


/* ALTERNATIVELY */


/* if you want the Register link to stay black and blue  when it's hovered 
   add this AFTER the .main-menu a.active CSS */


/*
.main-menu:hover a.register-link{
  color: #0095ff;
  background: #000;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <a href="#">Log In</a>
  <a href="#" class="active register-link">Register</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Language</a>
</div>
```

**If you want to apply the style *only* when the Register link is active**: In this case, you, would apply the style using `.main-menu:hover a.active.register-link`.

If you want the Register link to go green on hover, you'll also need to add `.main-menu:hover a.active.register-link:hover` to the existing `.main-menu a.active:hover` rule.

Code for this case:

```css
.main-menu {
  width: 170px;
}

.floating-menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 26px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 35%;
}

.floating-menu div a {
  /**text-align: center;**/
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.main-menu a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444950;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.main-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #00B200;
}

.main-menu a.active {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #00B200;
}

.main-menu:hover a.active.register-link {
  color: #0095ff;
  background: #000;
}

.main-menu:hover a.active.register-link:hover,
.main-menu a.active:hover {
  background-color: #00B200;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <a href="#">Log In</a>
  <a href="#" class="active register-link">Register</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Language</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can easily do this by adding following code:

```css
.main-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #eee!important;
  color: #00B200!important;
}

.main-menu:hover .register {
  background-color: #00B200;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <a href="#">Log In</a>
  <a href="#" class="register">Register</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Language</a>
</div>
```